# Instantiating a namedspaced class within another namespaced class

Tags: php, namespaces

I do not know if I got the title of the question right but I have a doubt I am facing while creating objects from namespaced classes.

So, this project has an index.php and an Inc folder inside the root of the project. The inc folder has folders -  Base ( with 
Enqueue.php), Pages (with Admin.php) and Init.php .In the index.php we are 
autoloading the Inc folder( which has a namespace of Inc ) and calling 
register_services() in the Init class

Here is the index.php file :

```
<?php
if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php' ) ) {
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    if ( class_exists( 'Inc\\Init' ) ) {
    Inc\Init::register_services();
        }
}
```

The Inc/Base/Enqueue.php

```
<?php 

namespace Inc\Base;

class Enqueue
{
    public function register() {
        echo 'enque register';
    }
```

The Inc/Pages/Admin.php :

```
<?php
namespace Inc\Pages;

class Admin
{
    public function register() {
        echo 'admin register';
    }

}
```

The Inc/Init.php :

```
<?php

namespace Inc;

final class Init
{
    /**
     * Store all the classes inside an array
     * @return array Full list of classes
     */
    public static function get_services() 
    {
        return [
            Pages\Admin::class,  // why Pages\Admin 
            Base\Enqueue::class
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Loop through the classes, initialize them, 
     * and call the register() method if it exists
     * @return
     */
    public static function register_services() 
    {
        foreach ( self::get_services() as $class){
                        $service = self::instantiate( $class );
            if ( method_exists( $service, 'register' ) ) {
                $service->register();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the class
     * @param  class $class    class from the services array
     * @return class instance  new instance of the class
     */
    private static function instantiate( $class )
    {
        echo $class;
                $service = new $class();
        return $service;
    }
}
```

So in the Init class, we have :

```
public static function get_services() 
    {
        return [
            Pages\Admin::class,  
            Base\Enqueue::class
        ];
    }
```

This returns as an array both the Qualified Names of the class that is Inc\Pages
\Admin and Inc\Base\Enqueue . Later we instantiate the class like below in the 
Init class  :

```
private static function instantiate( $class )
    {
        echo $class;
                $service = new $class();
        return $service;
    }
```

My question is since we are already in the namespace Inc in the Init class , wont instantiating the class by calling it starting from Inc again ( that is Inc
\Pages\Admin or Inc\Base\Enqueue ) lead it to search for the class in the namespace 'Inc\Inc\Pages\Admin' or 'Inc\Inc\Pages\Enqueue'? My code works all right though. Is my understanding of how namespaces work not right or am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Literals* are resolved against the current namespace, strings are always assumed/expected/required to be the fully qualified name.

This is your literal:

```
namespace Inc;

Pages\Admin::class
```

This literal `Pages\Admin` is resolved against the current namespace and resolves to `Inc\Pages\Admin`. So the value of `Pages\Admin::class` here is `'Inc\Pages\Admin'`. You then pass this string around and end up doing:

```
new $class()  // where $class = 'Inc\Pages\Admin'
```

Since you're instantiating from a string, that string is treated as being the fully qualified name and is *not* resolved against the current namespace. Precisely because strings can be passed around between namespaces, and it would be impossible to clearly know what namespace they're supposed to belong to.